# \url with \ldots

Tags: hyperref, urls

Using `\url` from `\usepackage{hyperref}`.
Trying to do `\url{\dots/path/to/somewhere}`, pdflatex complains

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tect \global \let \OT1\textellipsis 
                                                  .\kern \fontdimen 3\font ....
l.2 ... \url{\ldots/path/to/somewhere}
```

and renders it, if I Q out of the run

```
\protect\global\let\OT1\textellipsis. \kern\fontdimen3\font.\kern\fontdimen3\font.\kern\fontdimen3\ font\OT1\textellipsis/path/to/somewhere
```

Is there another way of adding an ellipsis to a URL?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I something stopping you from writing `...` instead of, say,  `\textellipsis`?

Comment: Nothing stopping me, but it fails the same way

Comment: Sorry, read you comment wrong.  If I write ... instead of any dots command, flycheck suggests I should use \lots instead, and the resulting dots don't typeset properly, i.e. too far apart.  I'm actually doing .\kern\fontdimen3.\kern\fontdimen3 now, but was wondering why \ldots inside \url is triggering the warning.

Comment: Here's an excellent example of how a machine learning-based suggestion can be utterly misleading. Clearly, not all cases of `...` are candidates for replacement with `\ldots` or, for that matter, `\textellipsis`.

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and stop worrying about how to fine-tune the pretty-printing of characters in a URL string. Instead, just load the `xurl` package (*in addition to* the `hyperref` package) and encase URL strings in `\url{...}` wrappers. If consecutive period characters (aka "dots" or "full stops") happen to be present in a URL string, *so what*?! What matters to your readers is that they can copy and paste the URL string into their web browsers or, if the URL string has been made into a hyperlink, that they can click on the URL string and be taken straight to the right destination.

Comment: I'm trying to use \url to print a DOS path. The ellipsis is to avoid having a large path, the readers know where to anchor it. Using hyperref, with or without xurl, the three dots look like, well three dots, instead of a nicely kerned eliipsis.  Replacing the three dots with \ldots makes \url barf.  It's interesting that I can use \kern\fontdimen3 with \urt but not \ldots. I could use \path too, but that just prints the whole thing out, which is much better "diagnostic" that I'm doing something silly.  Not going to argue if my use of ellipsis on a path is the proper thing to do or not.

Comment: You write, "It's interesting that I can use `\kern\fontdimen`3 with `\url` but not `\ldots`". Well, `\kern` and `\fontdimen` are so-called TeX primitives, not "macros"; in contrast, `\ldots` is a macro. TeX is a so-called macro expansion language; macros get expanded, but primitives do not. (My apologies for the excessive amount of TeX jargon!) `\url` rightfully chokes on `\ldots` because there's no way that a properly constructed URL should *ever* contain a TeX macro. `\url` cannot choke on `\kern` and `\fontdimen` because they aren't expanded (in the TeX sense of the word). (to be cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd from previous comment) But a proper URL string should never contain any TeX primitives either. Neither TeX macros nor TeX primitives have *any business* being in a URL string. My main concern is this: Why do you think it's a good idea to insert TeX primitives in a URL string? Are your aesthetic sensibilities really that badly offended by the presence of an infelicitously typeset group of three dots that you think it might be a good idea to replace `...` with `.\kern\fontdimen3.\kern\fontdimen3.`? Guess what? Your readers do not share this noble concern of yours. Let it rest.